# Stringr function str_extract_all() suddenly not working on any dataset I try

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I went to rerun some R code I have been using for years and seemingly overnight it stopped working. Nothing about the data changed, nothing about the code changed, but the function, str_extract_all, from the R package stringr, no longer works.

The data comes from a .txt file that's an output from a bayesian diet model. I am trying to make it a table so I can look at diet by individual. It looks like this:

Wolves:

| Individual | Proportion |
| --- | --- |
| Wolf1.Deer | .50 |
| Wolf1.Elk | .30 |
| Wolf1.Moose | .20 |
| Wolf2.Deer | .40 |
| Wolf2.Elk | .35 |
| Wolf2.Moose | .25 |

The line of code I have been using all this time to create the new food column is:

```
Wolves$Food <- unlist(
  str_extract_all(
    Wolves$Individual, 
    c("Deer", "Elk", "Moose")
  ), 
  use.names=FALSE
)
```

So the new data would look like this:

```
| Individual | Proportion| Food
| ---------- | --------- |
| Wolf1.Deer | .50       | Deer
| Wolf1.Elk  | .30       | Elk
| Wolf1.Moose| .20       | Moose
| Wolf2.Deer | .40       | Deer 
| Wolf2.Elk  | .35       | Elk
| Wolf2.Moose| .25       | Moose
```

and then I would be able to run stats by food group.

But now I suddenly get this error: Error in `str_extract_all()`:
! Can't recycle `string` (size 6) to match `pattern` (size 3).

This is a recurring error across about a dozen datasets I'm using the code on, so I don't think it's a problem with the data. I'm not R savvy enough to know what is actually going on with the workings of the function, but any help would be appreciated.

If it's any use, when I run last_trace on the error I get:

```
├─base::unlist(...)
 2. ├─stringr::str_extract_all(Wolves$Individual, c("Deer", "Elk", "Moose"))
 3. │ └─stringr:::check_lengths(string, pattern)
 4. │   └─vctrs::vec_size_common(...)
 5. └─vctrs::stop_incompatible_size(...)
 6.   └─vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
 7.     └─vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
 8.       └─rlang::abort(message, class = c(class, "vctrs_error"), ..., call = call)
```

I've tried reinstalling the packages, reinstalling R, not loading stringr and just loading tidyverse. I've tried taking out the unlist() part of the code. I've tried it on many different datasets with many different food names inserted. All to no avail.

Answer (score 5):

`stringr` changed as of v1.5.0. [Per the changelog](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html), it no longer automatically recycles the `pattern` argument unless it is of length one. Before it was doubling your match pattern of length 3 to match your data of length 6. You either need to manually double your match pattern

```
unlist(
  str_extract_all(
   Wolves$Individual, 
    c("Deer", "Elk", "Moose", "Deer", "Elk", "Moose")
  ), 
  use.names=FALSE
)
```

or use a single regex

```
unlist(
  str_extract_all(
   Wolves$Individual, 
    "Deer|Elk|Moose"
  ), 
  use.names=FALSE
)
```

or match everything after the `.` to the end

```
unlist(
  str_extract_all(
   Wolves$Individual, 
    "(?<=\\.).*$"
  ), 
  use.names=FALSE
)
```

Comment: This was the solution, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can install a specific version of `stringr` using `devtools::install_version`.

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_version("stringr", version = "1.4.1")
```

With version `1.4.1` your code works and gives:

```
library("stringr")
unlist(
  str_extract_all(
    Wolves$Individual, 
    c("Deer", "Elk", "Moose")
  ), 
  use.names=FALSE
)
#[1] "Deer"  "Elk"   "Moose" "Deer"  "Elk"   "Moose"
```

As an *base* alternative I would use `sub` to get the same result:

```
sub(".*\\.", "", Wolves$Individual)
#[1] "Deer"  "Elk"   "Moose" "Deer"  "Elk"   "Moose"
```

Data

```
Wolves <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="Individual    Proportion
Wolf1.Deer  .50
Wolf1.Elk   .30
Wolf1.Moose     .20
Wolf2.Deer  .40
Wolf2.Elk   .35
Wolf2.Moose     .25")
```

Comment: I figured it had something to do with a package update, thanks!

Comment: Yes, and to use an older version and be able to run the old scripts without changing them you can use `devtools::install_version`.

Comment: Yes that's a great tip to know! Save me some headaches in the future.